# Dynamically updating data with React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to update data every 5 seconds, how can I do it with Redux actions? 
Now I use this approach, but Im not sure that it is good idea. Maybe there are better ways to do it? Can I do it in actions? Thanks for answers and sorry for my English)

```
class Example extends Component {   
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.interval = null;
this.state = {
  data: props.data
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.updateData(this.props.id)
}


updateData = currentId => {
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  this.props.getData(currentId);
}, 5000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 const self = this;
 clearInterval(self.interval);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.data!== nextProps.data) {
   this.setState({data: nextProps.data});
  } else if(this.props.id !== nextProps.id) {
   this.updateData(nextProps.id)
  }
}  
render() {return(...html here)}
}

export default connect(
 store => ({
data: store.data,
 }),
 {getData}
)(Example);
```

Comment: Anytime you want to update data with Redux you have to call an action creator.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is good in terms of the approach of setting an interval. However, there is no need to copy your `props.data` into state. You can remove the local state, and in your render method, you can directly reference `props.data` and it will re-render every time the prop changes. If you want this interval to happen continuously through the lifetime of your app, you can move it to a higher level in the component hierarchy, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your snippet a little bit. Are you sure you need to copy `props` into the `state` of the component? If you're just rendering based on the props, and the state is never changed, you don't have to do this.

I'm also assuming that `getData` in your code is a redux action creator, defined somewhere else.

The `setInterval` logic you wrote is mostly correct I'd say. You want to dispatch a Redux action every 5 seconds, as long as the component lives. Fair enough.

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.interval = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.pollForData(this.props.id)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.id !== nextProps.id) {
            this.pollForData(nextProps.id);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    pollForData(id) {
        // First clear old interval if one exists
        if (this.interval) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        this.interval = setInterval(
            () => this.props.getData(id),
            5000
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (...html here)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.data,
    id: // ? was this missing in your code? where is this.props.id coming from?
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getData // I'm assuming you defined this somewhere else
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(Example);
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I do it with Redux actions?

Use [`redux async`](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) action.

install [`redux thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_DATA",
            Id: currentId
        })
    }
}, 5000);
```

In REDUCERS class,define one more action type `GET_DATA` which will call

`getData` with above signature.